# node.js How to search for a value in an array in a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, search, indexof

This is hard to explain so I'll just show an example.
I have an array of specific keywords, like so:

```
const keywordArr = ['jim', 'john'];
```

then I have a string:

```
const message = 'Hello john, how are you doing today?'
```

I would like to check if `message` contains a value from `keywordArr`. I know I could loop through each value in `keywordArr` and check like this:

```
keywordArr.forEach(function(word) {
    if (message.toLowerCase().includes(word)) {
         rest of code here..
    }
}
```

However, I get around 5 messages each second, so that method would be very performance consuming. Is there any efficient way to do this?

Comment: You're either going to loop the `keywordArr` or `message` multiple times. Perhaps run some performance tests for your use-case?

Comment: You can try regular expressions.

Comment: you should check this first: [Multiple Pattern String Matching Algorithm](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/314191170_Single_and_Multiple_Pattern_String_Matching_Algorithm), if the min length of keywords are long, I prefer to using WM.

Comment: If performance is all you care about and it is like to top most priority then I would suggest looking at some algorithms like these  [Knuth-Morris-Pratt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm). and [Boyer–Moore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm) compare them (possibly with regular expression as well) and choose accordingly.

Comment: I don't think that 5 messages per second warrants hyper-performant code. Though that certainly depends on how long your `message` is and how many keywords you have.

Comment: @pushkin 5 messages per second probably not, but this can get pretty nasty pretty quickly.

Comment: @MatusDubrava, BM and KMP is single pattern algorithm, multiple patterns should be WM or AC etc.

Comment: I found something interesting, [PatternMatchingAlgorithms in Github](https://github.com/foo123/PatternMatchingAlgorithms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Return true/false

We can do this using `reduce` and `includes`, if your not into the whole `RegExp` thing:

```js
const keywordArr = ['jim', 'john'];

const message = 'Hello john, how are you doing today?'

let has = keywordArr.reduce((r,v) => message.toLowerCase().includes(v.toLowerCase()) || r, false)

console.log(has)
```

This will match with case insensitivity. Remove both of the `toLowerCaser()` methods if you want a case sensitive match.

### Return a name

We can modify the reduce function by adding `&& v` which will return the value instead of a `true/false` value. We also will modify the starting value from `false` to an empty string.

```js
const keywordArr = ['jim', 'john'];

const message = 'Hello john, how are you doing today?'

let name = keywordArr.reduce((r,v) => message.toLowerCase().includes(v.toLowerCase()) && v || r, '')

console.log(name)
```

### Return an array of names

If we want to return a list of all names within the string, we can replace `&& v` with `&& r.concat(v)` then replace the starting value from an empty string to an empty array.

```js
const keywordArr = ['jim', 'john', 'paul'];

const message = 'Hello john, how are you doing today? -- jim'

let names = keywordArr.reduce((r,v) => message.toLowerCase().includes(v.toLowerCase()) && r.concat(v) || r, [])

console.log(names)
```

Comment: Calling `toLowerCase()` on the same `message` in every iteration isn't doing you any favors in the performance department.

Comment: It could be put on the main message, but if it needs to be used somewhere else as-is, you then lose your casing. Creating a temp var would solve that though.

Comment: This method works great, is there a way to get **which** word is in the sentence? Which in this case would be `john`, how can I let the code know that?

Comment: I have updated the answer with a second example that returns the string instead of a `true/false` value

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for array and [`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to check string contain or not.

**DEMO**

```js
const keywordArr = ['jim', 'john'],
  message = 'Hello john, how are you doing today?';

keywordArr.forEach(v => {
  if (message.match(v)) console.log(`message contain ${v}`);
});
```

Comment: As I said before, I wouldn't want to forEach through the array everytime as I get 5 messages a second-- and everytime the message is received, the code runs again. However, what I like about this is that it shows which word is in the array (in this case is `john`). Is there any other way to do this more efficiently?

Comment: For other way you can aslo use [`RegExp.prototype.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test).

Example like this `RegExp(['jim', 'john'].join("|")).test('Hello john, how are you doing today?')`

Answer (score 1):

Check if the array contains any of the words using [`RegExp.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/eKxaiN/1) example).

```js
const keywordArr = ['jim', 'john'];

const message = 'Hello john, how are you doing today?'

const pattern = new RegExp(`\\b${keywordArr.join('|')}\\b`, 'gi');
const contains = pattern.test(message);

console.log(contains);
```

Comment: This works great iif none of the keywords contain any regex special characters. (And if the list if keywords isn't very long.)

Comment: And you can always [escape the keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446170/escape-string-for-use-in-javascript-regex).